# oracle connectivity issue with php (xampp)

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface, ora-12170

I need to connect oracle 11g database with my xampp server and I need both local and remote connection. For that what I did is first I installed the oracle 11g express edition and the downloaded the `instantclient-basic-nt-11.2.0.4.0` and placed the extracted folder `instantclient_11_2` in `C:\` then I set the environment variable (system variables) and my path value looks like this `path=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\instantclient_11_2`.

Then I removed the `;` before `extension=php_oci8.dll` and `extension=php_oci8_11g.dll` from the `php.ini` file. Then first I tried to connect with my local database:

```
$tns_turjo = '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.13)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))'; // tns of another pc
$tns_ishrak = '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.18)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))'; // tns of my pc

$conn = oci_connect('system', 'cibl123*#', $tns_turjo);
if($conn) {
    echo "connected";
}
else {
    echo "not";
}
```

When I pass `$tns_ishrak` it echoes `connected` but when I try to access the oracle database of another pc i.e. use the `$tns_turjo` then it echoes `not` and the error is

```
Message: oci_connect(): ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
```

I have also changed the username and password while connecting to another pc.

N.B. After enabling the .dll extensions from the php.ini file whenever I start the Apache I get a pop up warning in xampp which is `Module 'oci8' is already loaded`

How can I solve the remote connection issue?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the InstantClient installed; Oracle XE includes a full Oracle client.

There are many possible reasons why a remote connection does not work, but the most common (in my experience) are:

1. The firewall on your PC is blocking the connection.
2. The firewall on the remote PC is blocking the connection.
3. The TNS listener is not running on the remote PC.
4. The connection string is wrong.

Can you connect to the remote PC without PHP?  Have you tried via SQL*Plus or simply a `tnsping` command?

---

> N.B. After enabling the .dll extensions from the php.ini file whenever I start the Apache I get a pop up warning in xampp which is `Module 'oci8' is already loaded`

That's quite self-explanatory: you are trying to load the OCI module more than once.  You should only have **one** OCI module enabled so if you've something like the below in your `php.ini` file then that's the problem:

```
extension=php_oci8.dll
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll
```

Only `php_oci8_11g.dll` should be enabled since that's the version you have installed.